# Minor space loss after creating partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

First off, I'd like to emphasize that this is more a curiosity than wanting to recover a very small amount of space.

I created a 10 GiB NTFS partition (split off from what was originally a 1.4 TiB partition). Explorer reports the partition as 10736365568 bytes. This is 1028 KiB short of 10 GiB. What is the 1028 KiB used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You'll rarely have a partition of *exactly* 10gb (or any other specific size) because partitions must be set up on disk sector boundaries, so there's always a little bit of "rounding" that happens.
2. If you're looking at the formatted size, then some of the space is used by filesystem overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely for File System Accounting/Management.

It could also be a rounding error in the values you see - but the management answer is pretty likely it. I guess it may be an extended/logical partition accounting thing too..